# Python3 + uwsgi - special language chars in terminal

Tags: python, encoding, terminal, uwsgi, utf

I think, that topic was discussed a few times, but for me it is still unclear.
First, I start from a used OS: I working on a remote shell, on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
/etc/default/locale below:

```
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
#LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8
#LANGUAGE=POSIX
```

I have some py file: *test4.py*

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

va =  sys.getfilesystemencoding()
print('File system encoding')
print(va)

vb = sys.getdefaultencoding()
print('Default encoding')
print(vb)

dict = {'foo' : 'bar',
        'cebula' : 'łąśćźżęó'
        }

for key, value in dict.items():
        print(key + ' : ' + value)
```

when I try to call this file:

```
File system encoding
ascii
Default encoding
utf-8
foo : bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test/test4.py", line 18, in <module>
print(key + ' : ' + value)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 9-16: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If before calling script, I use:

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
```

and then, I run script:

```
File system encoding
ascii
Default encoding
utf-8
cebula : łąśćźżęó
foo : bar
```

All works good.

So, I am going to my Django app running using uwsgi (there is no matter, that I run it in virtualenv or not).
On *.ini file (config) I have block:

```
env = PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
```

Script code (cutted, only for show what is going on):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def command(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        for key, value in sorted(request.POST.items()):
            print(key + ' : ' + value)
```

If *value* has language-specific letters (in this case - Polish):

```
print(key + ' : ' + value)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 10-12: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If I add to *uwsgi.ini* following lines:

`env = LC_ALL=pl_PL.UTF-8` OR `env = LANG=pl_PL.utf-8`

The app work stable.

Questions:

a)Why Python3 don't need to set this locales, even temporary, but uwsgi need them to parse correctly language-specific characters?

b) Which function/method should I use, when I know that printable-variables will be showed in terminal (as above), and they will contain language-specific characters. I want to stay with en_US.UTF-8 encoding.